# BASH_ALIASES not equal to alias

Tags: bash, shell, alias, variable

I've just recognized that (in Debian 7, within Bash  4.2.37) the output of `BASH_ALIASES` isn't equal to that of `alias` – which, according to [gnu.org's Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables), should be the case:

> `BASH_ALIASES`
>
> An associative array variable whose members correspond to the internal list of aliases as maintained by the alias builtin. (see
>   Bourne Shell Builtins). Elements added to this array appear in the
>   alias list; unsetting array elements cause aliases to be removed from the alias list.

I get `ls='ls --color=auto'` for `alias` but an empty line for `BASH_ALIASES`.

### Question:

*Should it be that way? Could this cause any problems in the future*?

As I am just curious and battling with all the options for each command causing me enough headache so I really keep quite a distance from making things even more complicated with homebrew aliases, I wonder if this could be a source of trouble in the near future…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BASH_ALIASES` is an associative array, so to display it:

```
$ declare -p BASH_ALIASES
declare -A BASH_ALIASES='([ls]="ls --color=auto" )'
```

Or:

```
$ for k in "${!BASH_ALIASES[@]}"; do printf '%s => %s\n' "$k" "${BASH_ALIASES[$k]}"; done
ls => ls --color=auto
```

Comment: This helps quite a lot, but still: As I (think to know) that one has to `declare` one's own associative arrays, I didn't thought of having to do this for the system too… which sounds a bit confusing me (as I'm new to Bash scripting and just getting a grip on Arrays at all)

Comment: @chirp, what do you mean? There's nothing to declare. `BASH_ALIASES` is already defined, `declare -p` is to <b>p</b>rint its declaration.